# Degrees of freedom and k-fold cross validation dillema

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, cross-validation, t-test, degrees-of-freedom

I have several machine learning k-fold cross-validation experiments to run **in a very short time**, and have the following possible dilemma that I need some help to understand: if I choose a k that is low (say, 5), my experiments will run fast (something I want), but I will result in a population (vectors) of 5 metrics (say, accuracy), each vector for each machine learning approach I am using.

My question is, I would like to use these vectors as input to statistical tests and I have some fear about the low degrees of freedom of such populations that possibly can hinder my analysis. Am I correct about it? what is the population size that is recommended for a reliable statistical test analysis? or is it ok to use low degrees of freedom here?